# Spring 3.0.3 and JMS 2.0 Support

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jms, spring-jms

I am upgrading my application's JMS from `1.1` to `2.0`.

My application is currently having `Spring 3.0.3` and uses `JMSTemplete`.

**Is there any official ( Spring or JMS ) documentation mentioning the support for JMS 2.0 with Spring 3.0.3?**

I was actually searching it in order to find out weather any Spring related change is required in my application or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work since the 1.1 APIs are still supported in 2.0.

If you want to use the new 2.0 shared subscription feature (on topics), you will need to [upgrade to at least Spring 4.1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11969).

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russel.